# return and call dynamic string array

Tags: c++, string, function, vector

I created a class:

```
    Data::Data(char szFileName[MAX_PATH]) {

    string sIn;
    int i = 1;

    ifstream infile;
    infile.open(szFileName);
    infile.seekg(0,ios::beg);

    std::vector<std::string> fileRows;
    while ( getline(infile,sIn ) )
    {
      fileRows.push_back(sIn);
    }
}
```

after that i created this:

```
std::vector<std::string> Data::fileContent(){
        return fileRows;
}
```

After that I would like to call this `fileContent()` somewhere, something like this:

```
Data name(szFileName);
MessageBox(hwnd, name.fileContent().at(0).c_str() , "About", MB_OK);
```

But this doesnt work... How to call this?

Comment: What is `Adatkezeles`?

Comment: I guess you want to make `fileRows` as member of `Data`?

Comment: sorry Adatkezeles = Data
Data name(szFileName);
MessageBox(hwnd, name.fileContent().at(0).c_str() , "About", MB_OK);

and i got this error:
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
  what():  vector::_M_range_check

Comment: @David: Please use the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/15476074/edit) link to update your question with this information. Also, you probably want `Data::fileContent()` to (a) be `const`-qualified and (b) to return `std::vector<std::string>` *by reference*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
std::vector<std::string> fileRows;
while ( getline(infile,sIn ) )
{
   fileRows.push_back(sIn);
}
```

does not work because you declare fileRows in the constructor, once the constructor ends `fileRows` is destroyed.

What you need to do is to move the fileRows declaration outside of the constructor and make it a class member:

```
class Data
{
...

   std::vector<std::string> fileRows;
};
```

then it will be shared by all functions in the class.

Answer (score 1):

You could do like this:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class Data
{
public:
  Data(const std::string& FileName)  // use std::string instead of char array
  {
     // load data to fileRows
  }

  std::string fileContent(int index) const  // and you may don't want to return a copy of fiileRows
  {
      return fileRows.at(index);
  }

private:
    std::vector<std::string> fileRows;
};
```